# How can I write the query bellow efficiently and cleaner?

Tags: mysql

First, I am selecting from two different databases, db1 and db2. From each database. On db1, I am counting results based on a condition from one column based on the data in that column. Same applies for db2.

```
    SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db1.table1) AS Column1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db1.table1 where  
                          table1.X ='a') AS Column2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db1.table1 where  
                         table1.X = 'b') AS Column3,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db1.table1 where 
                         table1.X = 'c') AS Column4,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db1.table1 where 
                          table1.X = 'd') AS Column5,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db1.table1 where
                          table1.X = 'e') AS Column6,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db2.table2 where
                          table2.Y = 'f') AS Column7,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db2.table2 where
                          table2.Y = 'g') AS Column8,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db2.table2 where
                          table2.Y = 'h') AS Column9,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db2.table2 where
                          table2.Y = 'i') AS Column10;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like that :

```
SELECT 
    MAX(Column1) AS Column1,
    MAX(Column2) AS Column2,
    MAX(Column3) AS Column3,
    MAX(Column4) AS Column4,
    MAX(Column5) AS Column5,
    MAX(Column6) AS Column6,
    MAX(Column7) AS Column7,
    MAX(Column8) AS Column8,
    MAX(Column9) AS Column9,
    MAX(Column10) AS Column10
FROM
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(X) AS Column1,
            SUM(X = 'a') AS Column2,
            SUM(X = 'b') AS Column3,
            SUM(X = 'c') AS Column4,
            SUM(X = 'd') AS Column5,
            SUM(X = 'e') AS Column6,
            NULL AS Column7,
            NULL AS Column8,
            NULL AS Column9,
            NULL AS Column10
    FROM
        _ds_stack_table1 AS table1 UNION ALL SELECT 
        NULL AS Column1,
            NULL AS Column2,
            NULL AS Column3,
            NULL AS Column4,
            NULL AS Column5,
            NULL AS Column6,
            SUM(Y = 'f') AS Column7,
            SUM(Y = 'g') AS Column8,
            SUM(Y = 'h') AS Column9,
            SUM(Y = 'i') AS Column10
    FROM
        _ds_stack_table2 AS table2) D;
```

SQL Fiddle link :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1eb5cf/1/0

Comment: Whilst I do like the solution I have run into the following problems with it:                                                              1.    table1.COUNT(*) AS Column1 - throws a syntax error  so I changed the first 
       line to  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1.X) AS Column1                                            2.    The results are wrong. The numbers are not right.

Comment: Please give us more info on the data you have on your table

Comment: The results do not match the data in the table. For example  : There are only 8 places where table1.X ='a' but the result came up as 36.

Comment: That is not working out and I see now. Diving the results just brings up even more odd numbers out

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to get the information but it doesn't have to be *exactly* those column field name results then I would use two queries:

```
SELECT `X`,count(*) as `c` FROM `table1` GROUP BY `X` WITH ROLLUP;
SELECT `Y`,count(*) as `c` FROM `table2` GROUP BY `Y` WITH ROLLUP;
```

You need to loop through the results of each query. Each row will have one identifier (X or Y) and one count (c), except for the last row. The last row will have NULL (naming may vary depending on language you are using to make the queries - PHP, Python, etc.) for the identifier and the total for the count.

This also has the advantage that if you add new values of X or Y that you want to count, the query will not change.

Comment: @magerine I could help a little more if I knew what language you are using for the application. But basically a MySQL result is normally a set of rows of data. They can be simple fields, COUNT() or even more complex. Instead of trying to get all the counts as one row, my solution (a) splits it into 2 queries for the 2 tables and then (b) returns a total for each X (or Y) together with the value of X (or Y). To put it another way, you are retrieving "all" the X (or Y) values, each with a total, instead of saying "give me SPECIFICALLY 'this' X and its total".

Comment: Oh, I see, But I do need  to get certain values SPECIFICALLY.

Comment: @magerine I have had similar situations in my own programming. What I would do in a similar instance is to write the queries the way I did and collect the data in an array/object/dict (terminology depends on your application language) and then retrieve data from there. If this was PHP then I might assign results in a loop through the query with something like `$counts[$result['X']] = $result['c']` and then outside the loop I would reference what I needed `print `$counts['a']`. But the specifics will vary greatly by language.

Comment: Great, I will use this in the future.